# SpresenseとEhernetモジュールW5500-etherを用いたUDP通信にて大容量のデータが送信できません

Tags: spresense, arduino

現在、SpresenseとW5500-etherを使用してカメラモジュールで撮影した映像をUDP通信にて送信するシステムをArduino IDEにて開発しています。
そして、その前段階としてuint8_t配列のデータを送信しようとしたのですが、データ量が1472バイトを超過すると、1472バイト以降のデータを送信することができません。通常のEthernetを経由したUDP通信の場合、1500バイトを超えると自動的にパケットが分割されて送信されるといった認識でしたが、Spresenseにはそのような機能はないのでしょうか？
また、この問題を回避するために配列を1400バイトごとに分割して送信したのですが、動作周期が目標の30Hzに届かず、また途中でSpresense側の動作が停止してしまいます。
そのため、可能であれば通常のUDP通信のように1回の通信で送信したいのですが、何か方法はありませんでしょうか？
以下にコードを記載しますので、ご参照ください。長くなってしまい申し訳ありませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <Camera.h>
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------- //
//Add-onボード用インクルード
#include <SPI.h>
#include "src/Ethernet.h"
#include "src/M24C64.h"
#include "src/EthernetUdp.h"
#define UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE 5000
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------- //
//Add-onボード搭載EEPROMへのアクセス用
M24C64 eep;
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------- //
//Add-onボード用のSPIはSPI5となるため、本ライブラリ使用時は以下の定義が必要(socket.cpp内にて使用)
//参考：https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_spi_%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA
#define USE_SPRESENSE_SPI5
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------- //
#define data_size 5000
uint8_t data[data_size];

byte mac[] = {
  ****, ****, ****, ****, ****, ****
};
IPAddress ip(***, ***, ***, ***);
unsigned int localPort = 8888;

IPAddress remote(***, ***, ***, ***);
int pClocalPort = 8888;

EthernetUDP Udp;

bool isI2C(uint8_t address)
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(address);
  if (Wire.endTransmission() == 0)
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

void setup() {
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // W5500-Ether用の初期化方法
  digitalWrite(21, LOW);//W5500_Eth RESET# = HIGH
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(21, HIGH);//W5500_Eth RESET# = HIGH
  Ethernet.init(19);// use I2S_DIN pin for W5500 CS pin
  // W5500-Ether用のMACアドレス取得処理
  // I2C device scan
  Serial.print(F("I2C Devices(0x) : "));
  Wire.begin();
  //I2C spec. have reserved address!! these scanning escape it address.
  for (uint8_t ad = 0x08; ad < 0x77; ad++)
  {
    if (isI2C(ad))
    {
      Serial.print(ad, HEX);
      Serial.write(' ');
    }
  }
  Serial.write('\n');
  //EEPROM MAC ADDRESS read
  eep.init(0x57);
  Serial.println("MAC read from on board eeprom.");
  for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
  {
    mac[i] = eep.read(i);
    Serial.print(mac[i],HEX);
    Serial.print(":");
  }
  Serial.println("");
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("W5500 reset done.");
  
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  
  if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
    while (true) {
      delay(1);
    }
  }
  if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
  }

  for(int a = 0; a < data_size; a++){
    data[a] = 10;
  }
  Udp.begin(localPort);
}

void loop() {
  Udp.beginPacket(remote,pClocalPort);
  Udp.write(data, data_size);
  Udp.endPacket();
  delay(33);
}
```

Comment: W5500-Ether チップ (TCP/IP組み込みイーサネットコントローラー) の資料調べてみると
"Not support IP Fragmentation"
データグラムの断片化をサポートしない, ことになっています。
このため UDPでの MTUを超える長さのパケットも扱えないはず

参考:  [W5500](https://www.wiznet.io/product-item/w5500/)
(「回答」とは呼べなさそうなのでコメントに移行しました)

Comment: oririさん、ご回答ありがとうございました。添付された資料を確認してみると確かにorioriさんがおっしゃる様にデータグラムの断片化には対応してなさそうです。なのでデータを分割する方向で進めていきたいと思います。もし他に良い方法などがありましたら、ご教授いただけると幸いです。改めて、ご回答いただきありがとうございました。